# How to plot two or more overlapping 3-D Gaussian surfaces in the same graph in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot two or more overlapping Gaussian surfaces in the same graph, as below?
This is the code I have written, But the first surface is being covered by the second one. They are overlapping , But i want them to be displayed transparently

result obtained:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LSsW.png

code :https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/ms8cngXm

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def loaddata(filename,label):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    text = file.read()
    text=text.split('\n')
    file.close()
    dataset = list()
    for line in text:
        if len(line)>0:
            value = line.split()
            dataset.append([float(value[0]), float(value[1]), label])
    return dataset
def multivariate_gaussian(pos, mu, Sigma):
    n = mu.shape[0]
    Sigma_det = np.linalg.det(Sigma)
    Sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(Sigma)
    N = np.sqrt((2*np.pi)**n * Sigma_det)
    fac = np.einsum('...k,kl,...l->...', pos-mu, Sigma_inv, pos-mu)
    return np.exp(-fac / 2) / N

#this is just for maptype ignore this
_viridis_data = [[0.267004, 0.004874, 0.329415],
                 [0.268510, 0.009605, 0.335427],
                 [0.269944, 0.014625, 0.341379],
                 [0.271305, 0.019942, 0.347269],
                 [0.272594, 0.025563, 0.353093],
                 [0.273809, 0.031497, 0.358853],
                 [0.274952, 0.037752, 0.364543],
                 [0.276022, 0.044167, 0.370164],
                 [0.277018, 0.050344, 0.375715],
                 [0.277941, 0.056324, 0.381191],
                 [0.278791, 0.062145, 0.386592],
                 [0.279566, 0.067836, 0.391917],
                 [0.280267, 0.073417, 0.397163],
                 [0.280894, 0.078907, 0.402329],
                 [0.281446, 0.084320, 0.407414],
                 [0.281924, 0.089666, 0.412415],
                 [0.282327, 0.094955, 0.417331],
                 [0.282656, 0.100196, 0.422160],
                 [0.282910, 0.105393, 0.426902],
                 [0.283091, 0.110553, 0.431554],
                 [0.283197, 0.115680, 0.436115],
                 [0.283229, 0.120777, 0.440584],
                 [0.283187, 0.125848, 0.444960],
                 [0.283072, 0.130895, 0.449241],
                 [0.282884, 0.135920, 0.453427],
                 [0.282623, 0.140926, 0.457517],
                 [0.282290, 0.145912, 0.461510],
                 [0.281887, 0.150881, 0.465405],
                 [0.281412, 0.155834, 0.469201],
                 [0.280868, 0.160771, 0.472899],
                 [0.280255, 0.165693, 0.476498],
                 [0.279574, 0.170599, 0.479997],
                 [0.278826, 0.175490, 0.483397],
                 [0.278012, 0.180367, 0.486697],
                 [0.277134, 0.185228, 0.489898],
                 [0.276194, 0.190074, 0.493001],
                 [0.275191, 0.194905, 0.496005],
                 [0.274128, 0.199721, 0.498911],
                 [0.273006, 0.204520, 0.501721],
                 [0.271828, 0.209303, 0.504434],
                 [0.270595, 0.214069, 0.507052],
                 [0.269308, 0.218818, 0.509577],
                 [0.267968, 0.223549, 0.512008],
                 [0.266580, 0.228262, 0.514349],
                 [0.265145, 0.232956, 0.516599],
                 [0.263663, 0.237631, 0.518762],
                 [0.262138, 0.242286, 0.520837],
                 [0.260571, 0.246922, 0.522828],
                 [0.258965, 0.251537, 0.524736],
                 [0.257322, 0.256130, 0.526563],
                 [0.255645, 0.260703, 0.528312],
                 [0.253935, 0.265254, 0.529983],
                 [0.252194, 0.269783, 0.531579],
                 [0.250425, 0.274290, 0.533103],
                 [0.248629, 0.278775, 0.534556],
                 [0.246811, 0.283237, 0.535941],
                 [0.244972, 0.287675, 0.537260],
                 [0.243113, 0.292092, 0.538516],
                 [0.241237, 0.296485, 0.539709],
                 [0.239346, 0.300855, 0.540844],
                 [0.237441, 0.305202, 0.541921],
                 [0.235526, 0.309527, 0.542944],
                 [0.233603, 0.313828, 0.543914],
                 [0.231674, 0.318106, 0.544834],
                 [0.229739, 0.322361, 0.545706],
                 [0.227802, 0.326594, 0.546532],
                 [0.225863, 0.330805, 0.547314],
                 [0.223925, 0.334994, 0.548053],
                 [0.221989, 0.339161, 0.548752],
                 [0.220057, 0.343307, 0.549413],
                 [0.218130, 0.347432, 0.550038],
                 [0.216210, 0.351535, 0.550627],
                 [0.214298, 0.355619, 0.551184],
                 [0.212395, 0.359683, 0.551710],
                 [0.210503, 0.363727, 0.552206],
                 [0.208623, 0.367752, 0.552675],
                 [0.206756, 0.371758, 0.553117],
                 [0.204903, 0.375746, 0.553533],
                 [0.203063, 0.379716, 0.553925],
                 [0.201239, 0.383670, 0.554294],
                 [0.199430, 0.387607, 0.554642],
                 [0.197636, 0.391528, 0.554969],
                 [0.195860, 0.395433, 0.555276],
                 [0.194100, 0.399323, 0.555565],
                 [0.192357, 0.403199, 0.555836],
                 [0.190631, 0.407061, 0.556089],
                 [0.188923, 0.410910, 0.556326],
                 [0.187231, 0.414746, 0.556547],
                 [0.185556, 0.418570, 0.556753],
                 [0.183898, 0.422383, 0.556944],
                 [0.182256, 0.426184, 0.557120],
                 [0.180629, 0.429975, 0.557282],
                 [0.179019, 0.433756, 0.557430],
                 [0.177423, 0.437527, 0.557565],
                 [0.175841, 0.441290, 0.557685],
                 [0.174274, 0.445044, 0.557792],
                 [0.172719, 0.448791, 0.557885],
                 [0.171176, 0.452530, 0.557965],
                 [0.169646, 0.456262, 0.558030],
                 [0.168126, 0.459988, 0.558082],
                 [0.166617, 0.463708, 0.558119],
                 [0.165117, 0.467423, 0.558141],
                 [0.163625, 0.471133, 0.558148],
                 [0.162142, 0.474838, 0.558140],
                 [0.160665, 0.478540, 0.558115],
                 [0.159194, 0.482237, 0.558073],
                 [0.157729, 0.485932, 0.558013],
                 [0.156270, 0.489624, 0.557936],
                 [0.154815, 0.493313, 0.557840],
                 [0.153364, 0.497000, 0.557724],
                 [0.151918, 0.500685, 0.557587],
                 [0.150476, 0.504369, 0.557430],
                 [0.149039, 0.508051, 0.557250],
                 [0.147607, 0.511733, 0.557049],
                 [0.146180, 0.515413, 0.556823],
                 [0.144759, 0.519093, 0.556572],
                 [0.143343, 0.522773, 0.556295],
                 [0.141935, 0.526453, 0.555991],
                 [0.140536, 0.530132, 0.555659],
                 [0.139147, 0.533812, 0.555298],
                 [0.137770, 0.537492, 0.554906],
                 [0.136408, 0.541173, 0.554483],
                 [0.135066, 0.544853, 0.554029],
                 [0.133743, 0.548535, 0.553541],
                 [0.132444, 0.552216, 0.553018],
                 [0.131172, 0.555899, 0.552459],
                 [0.129933, 0.559582, 0.551864],
                 [0.128729, 0.563265, 0.551229],
                 [0.127568, 0.566949, 0.550556],
                 [0.126453, 0.570633, 0.549841],
                 [0.125394, 0.574318, 0.549086],
                 [0.124395, 0.578002, 0.548287],
                 [0.123463, 0.581687, 0.547445],
                 [0.122606, 0.585371, 0.546557],
                 [0.121831, 0.589055, 0.545623],
                 [0.121148, 0.592739, 0.544641],
                 [0.120565, 0.596422, 0.543611],
                 [0.120092, 0.600104, 0.542530],
                 [0.119738, 0.603785, 0.541400],
                 [0.119512, 0.607464, 0.540218],
                 [0.119423, 0.611141, 0.538982],
                 [0.119483, 0.614817, 0.537692],
                 [0.119699, 0.618490, 0.536347],
                 [0.120081, 0.622161, 0.534946],
                 [0.120638, 0.625828, 0.533488],
                 [0.121380, 0.629492, 0.531973],
                 [0.122312, 0.633153, 0.530398],
                 [0.123444, 0.636809, 0.528763],
                 [0.124780, 0.640461, 0.527068],
                 [0.126326, 0.644107, 0.525311],
                 [0.128087, 0.647749, 0.523491],
                 [0.130067, 0.651384, 0.521608],
                 [0.132268, 0.655014, 0.519661],
                 [0.134692, 0.658636, 0.517649],
                 [0.137339, 0.662252, 0.515571],
                 [0.140210, 0.665859, 0.513427],
                 [0.143303, 0.669459, 0.511215],
                 [0.146616, 0.673050, 0.508936],
                 [0.150148, 0.676631, 0.506589],
                 [0.153894, 0.680203, 0.504172],
                 [0.157851, 0.683765, 0.501686],
                 [0.162016, 0.687316, 0.499129],
                 [0.166383, 0.690856, 0.496502],
                 [0.170948, 0.694384, 0.493803],
                 [0.175707, 0.697900, 0.491033],
                 [0.180653, 0.701402, 0.488189],
                 [0.185783, 0.704891, 0.485273],
                 [0.191090, 0.708366, 0.482284],
                 [0.196571, 0.711827, 0.479221],
                 [0.202219, 0.715272, 0.476084],
                 [0.208030, 0.718701, 0.472873],
                 [0.214000, 0.722114, 0.469588],
                 [0.220124, 0.725509, 0.466226],
                 [0.226397, 0.728888, 0.462789],
                 [0.232815, 0.732247, 0.459277],
                 [0.239374, 0.735588, 0.455688],
                 [0.246070, 0.738910, 0.452024],
                 [0.252899, 0.742211, 0.448284],
                 [0.259857, 0.745492, 0.444467],
                 [0.266941, 0.748751, 0.440573],
                 [0.274149, 0.751988, 0.436601],
                 [0.281477, 0.755203, 0.432552],
                 [0.288921, 0.758394, 0.428426],
                 [0.296479, 0.761561, 0.424223],
                 [0.304148, 0.764704, 0.419943],
                 [0.311925, 0.767822, 0.415586],
                 [0.319809, 0.770914, 0.411152],
                 [0.327796, 0.773980, 0.406640],
                 [0.335885, 0.777018, 0.402049],
                 [0.344074, 0.780029, 0.397381],
                 [0.352360, 0.783011, 0.392636],
                 [0.360741, 0.785964, 0.387814],
                 [0.369214, 0.788888, 0.382914],
                 [0.377779, 0.791781, 0.377939],
                 [0.386433, 0.794644, 0.372886],
                 [0.395174, 0.797475, 0.367757],
                 [0.404001, 0.800275, 0.362552],
                 [0.412913, 0.803041, 0.357269],
                 [0.421908, 0.805774, 0.351910],
                 [0.430983, 0.808473, 0.346476],
                 [0.440137, 0.811138, 0.340967],
                 [0.449368, 0.813768, 0.335384],
                 [0.458674, 0.816363, 0.329727],
                 [0.468053, 0.818921, 0.323998],
                 [0.477504, 0.821444, 0.318195],
                 [0.487026, 0.823929, 0.312321],
                 [0.496615, 0.826376, 0.306377],
                 [0.506271, 0.828786, 0.300362],
                 [0.515992, 0.831158, 0.294279],
                 [0.525776, 0.833491, 0.288127],
                 [0.535621, 0.835785, 0.281908],
                 [0.545524, 0.838039, 0.275626],
                 [0.555484, 0.840254, 0.269281],
                 [0.565498, 0.842430, 0.262877],
                 [0.575563, 0.844566, 0.256415],
                 [0.585678, 0.846661, 0.249897],
                 [0.595839, 0.848717, 0.243329],
                 [0.606045, 0.850733, 0.236712],
                 [0.616293, 0.852709, 0.230052],
                 [0.626579, 0.854645, 0.223353],
                 [0.636902, 0.856542, 0.216620],
                 [0.647257, 0.858400, 0.209861],
                 [0.657642, 0.860219, 0.203082],
                 [0.668054, 0.861999, 0.196293],
                 [0.678489, 0.863742, 0.189503],
                 [0.688944, 0.865448, 0.182725],
                 [0.699415, 0.867117, 0.175971],
                 [0.709898, 0.868751, 0.169257],
                 [0.720391, 0.870350, 0.162603],
                 [0.730889, 0.871916, 0.156029],
                 [0.741388, 0.873449, 0.149561],
                 [0.751884, 0.874951, 0.143228],
                 [0.762373, 0.876424, 0.137064],
                 [0.772852, 0.877868, 0.131109],
                 [0.783315, 0.879285, 0.125405],
                 [0.793760, 0.880678, 0.120005],
                 [0.804182, 0.882046, 0.114965],
                 [0.814576, 0.883393, 0.110347],
                 [0.824940, 0.884720, 0.106217],
                 [0.835270, 0.886029, 0.102646],
                 [0.845561, 0.887322, 0.099702],
                 [0.855810, 0.888601, 0.097452],
                 [0.866013, 0.889868, 0.095953],
                 [0.876168, 0.891125, 0.095250],
                 [0.886271, 0.892374, 0.095374],
                 [0.896320, 0.893616, 0.096335],
                 [0.906311, 0.894855, 0.098125],
                 [0.916242, 0.896091, 0.100717],
                 [0.926106, 0.897330, 0.104071],
                 [0.935904, 0.898570, 0.108131],
                 [0.945636, 0.899815, 0.112838],
                 [0.955300, 0.901065, 0.118128],
                 [0.964894, 0.902323, 0.123941],
                 [0.974417, 0.903590, 0.130215],
                 [0.983868, 0.904867, 0.136897],
                 [0.993248, 0.906157, 0.143936]]
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

viridis = ListedColormap(_viridis_data, name='viridis')

plt.register_cmap(name='viridis', cmap=viridis)
plt.set_cmap(viridis)

filename=r"C:/Users/santhoskumar/Desktop/random/pattern/class1_rw.txt"
label=0
dataset1= loaddata(filename,label)
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows'.format(filename, len(dataset1)))
filename = r"C:/Users/santhoskumar/Desktop/random/pattern/class2_rw.txt"
label=1
dataset2 = loaddata(filename,label)
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows'.format(filename, len(dataset2)))
filename = r'C:/Users/santhoskumar/Desktop/random/pattern/class3_rw.txt'
label=2
dataset3 = loaddata(filename,label)
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows'.format(filename, len(dataset3)))



N = 600
X = np.linspace(200, 800, N)
Y = np.linspace(300, 1200, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

dataset=np.array(dataset1)
x,y,label=dataset.T
dat=x,y

dat=np.array(dat)
cov=np.cov(dat)
mu=np.mean(dat,axis=1)
print(mu)

# Pack X and Y into a single 3-dimensional array
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X
pos[:, :, 1] = Y


# The distribution on the variables X, Y packed into pos.
Z = multivariate_gaussian(pos, mu, cov)
minn=1e-15
for i in range(len(Z)):
    for j in range(len(Z[i])):
        Z[i][j]*=1e4

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax1=fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,rstride=30,cstride=30, linewidth=1,antialiased=True,cmap=viridis)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z,zdir='z',offset=-0.4,cmap=viridis)


ax.set_zlim(-0.4,0.40)
ax.set_zticks(np.linspace(0,0.40,5))
ax.view_init(27, -21)

dataset=np.array(dataset2)
x,y,label=dataset.T
dat=x,y

dat=np.array(dat)
cov=np.cov(dat)
mu=np.mean(dat,axis=1)
print(mu)

# Pack X and Y into a single 3-dimensional array
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))

pos[:, :, 0] = X
pos[:, :, 1] = Y


# The distribution on the variables X, Y packed into pos.
Z = multivariate_gaussian(pos, mu, cov)
minn=1e-15
for i in range(len(Z)):
    for j in range(len(Z[i])):
        Z[i][j]*=1e4


ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,rstride=20,cstride=20, linewidth=1,antialiased=True,color='red',cmap=viridis)
cset1 = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z,zdir='z',offset=-0.4,cmap=viridis)

ax.set_zlim(-0.4,0.40)
ax.set_zticks(np.linspace(0,0.40,5))
ax.view_init(27, -21)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I read this, and I think: So what happened? What specifically do you need help with? You can't expect us to just run your coded and guess the problem you are having. Maybe it is obvious, or maybe someone will try running in the wrong environment and have a totally different problem. or maybe someone will try running in the appropriate environment, and get exactly what you are expecting, if indeed the graph above is what you are expecting. No one knows. We will have a hard time answering this question if we don't know what you think is going wrong.

Comment: I have edited now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just have to call the plotting method multiple times such as:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x1, y1, z1,cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)
ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z2,cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)

ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The two or more classes will have different covariance matrix and mean vector, so z value changes,The image shows what i have to do  not what i did

Comment: Okay, so what you want to do is plot them all the same z, but at different x, y positions? I mean according to your code x and y stay the same, while only z changes. In the image however the graphs are not in the same x, y Position, while z seems to be the same.

Comment: Can you please suggest what class and method to use , to get exact graph like that

Comment: I do not know what library they used, but I would suggest you to have a look at this:
https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html
You could use `plot_trisurf`? But I do not see why `plot_surface()` should not work.

Comment: the first surface is blocking the second surface. that is the problem

Comment: @SANTHOSKUMAR [the figure in your original version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4RQA.png) used the _same_ baseline for the Gaussians, which makes a huge difference for data visualization. And if you change your surface plot to a mesh plot, or set non-trivial alpha (opacity) for your surfaces then it might be possible to see more from your peaks. But visualizing complex 3d data is always difficult, and matplotlib often has issues rendering complex 3d scenes correctly.